# How to determine recursive relations within dataset using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

The logic is for accounts to share revenue when generated.

The table holds revenue sharing agreements between accounts:

```
revenue_account,      distribution_account, percent, is_active
acc_28PGgHMdRskY4hnf, acc_8XENmdYBRygQxubA, 10.00,   1
acc_8XENmdYBRygQxubA, acc_MVHYsAvJ5c9hjura, 10.00,   1
acc_MVHYsAvJ5c9hjura, acc_ndk1tzj57phsfcwv, 10.00,   1
acc_MVHYsAvJ5c9hjura, acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA, 6.00,    1
acc_ndk1tzj57phsfcwv, acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA, 10.00,   1
acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA, acc_28PGgHMdRskY4hnf, 10.00,   1
```

When account `acc_MVHYsAvJ5c9hjura` generates $100, it shares with `acc_ndk1tzj57phsfcwv` and `acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA`, who then share with...

Every time I look at the data to decide the approach, I end up in a continuous loop. I do have authority to change the data structure, but I don't think it's necessary.

Maybe store looped values in a PHP array to check against in each recursion?

**Update**:

As requested, I'm updating this question with the desired results:

When revenue_account `acc_MVHYsAvJ5c9hjura`<sup>1</sup> receives a $100 payment. It pays distribution_account `acc_ndk1tzj57phsfcwv` 10% who also is a revenue_account that pays distribution_account `acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA` 10% who is also a revenue_account that pays distributuion_account `acc_28PGgHMdRskY4hnf` 10% who is also a revenue_account ...

<sup>1</sup> There's a second relationship branch with distribution_account `acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA` that must be processed also with the same logic.

The relationships between revenue_account and distribution_account are negotiated between parties. One revenue_account my perform gainsharing with many distribution_accounts.

Comment: From my perspective, `revenue_account` should not be recursive to `distribution_account`. If a `revenue_account` is expected to share percentages to several `disitribution_account`s, they should be linked as a One-To-Many relationship as opposed to self-referencing Many-To-Many.  That way you get a clean reference to all distribution accounts and percentages for a single `revenue_account` and allowing for fine-grained control over each `reveue_account`.

Comment: When a `distribution_account` receives payment, it then becomes a `revenue_account`

Comment: To better understand your intentions, please update your question to include the desired results/output. In its current structure, the schema would prevent a lot of reporting and aggregate data processing, relying on a lot of post-processing that could otherwise be performed with an SQL query. eg: `SELECT distribution_account, SUM(percent * :amount) FROM table WHERE revenue_account = 'acc_MVHYsAvJ5c9hjura' GROUP BY distribution_account` as a rough example.

Comment: @WillB. Thanks for the reply. I failed to provide enough detail. I'm glad you brought that to my attention.

Comment: The issue is that your current schema implies that `acc_28PGgHMdRskY4hnf` should 
 receive a percentage of it's own revenue when `acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA` does. I recommend looking into transitive closures or rather fully mapping out all `distribution_account` associations for each `revenue_account` to prevent the infinite recursion issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion recursion is a good solution, because I noticed there's a revenue account `acc_MVHYsAvJ5c9hjura` or the distribution account `acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA` which are used multiple times.

To prevent infinite recursion, I am using the `$visited` array. I've added a field `share` to see which amount was shared to the account.

```
$accounts = [
    ['revenue_account' => 'acc_28PGgHMdRskY4hnf', 'distribution_account' => 'acc_8XENmdYBRygQxubA', 'percent' => 10.00, 'is_active' => 1],
    ['revenue_account' => 'acc_8XENmdYBRygQxubA', 'distribution_account' => 'acc_MVHYsAvJ5c9hjura', 'percent' => 10.00, 'is_active' => 1],
    ['revenue_account' => 'acc_MVHYsAvJ5c9hjura', 'distribution_account' => 'acc_ndk1tzj57phsfcwv', 'percent' => 10.00, 'is_active' => 1],
    ['revenue_account' => 'acc_MVHYsAvJ5c9hjura', 'distribution_account' => 'acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA', 'percent' => 6.00, 'is_active' => 1],
    ['revenue_account' => 'acc_ndk1tzj57phsfcwv', 'distribution_account' => 'acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA', 'percent' => 10.00, 'is_active' => 1],
    ['revenue_account' => 'acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA', 'distribution_account' => 'acc_28PGgHMdRskY4hnf', 'percent' => 10.00, 'is_active' => 1],
];

function findAccounts($accounts, $revenue_account)
{
    foreach ($accounts as $index => $account) {
        if ($account['revenue_account'] === $revenue_account) {
            yield $index;
        }
    }
}

function share($amount, $revenue, &$accounts, &$visited = [])
{
    foreach (findAccounts($accounts, $revenue) as $currentIndex) {
        if(isset($visited[$currentIndex])) {
            continue;
        }
        $visited[$currentIndex] = true;
        $currentAccount = &$accounts[$currentIndex];

        foreach (findAccounts($accounts, $currentAccount['distribution_account']) as $nextIndex) {
            if (false === $nextIndex) {
                return;
            }
            $nextAccount = &$accounts[$nextIndex];
            $sum = ($amount / 100) * $nextAccount['percent'];
            $nextAccount['shared'] = isset($nextAccount['shared']) ? $nextAccount['shared'] + $sum : $sum;

            share($amount, $nextAccount['distribution_account'], $accounts, $visited);
        }
    }
}

share(100, 'acc_28PGgHMdRskY4hnf', $accounts);
print_r($accounts);
```

results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [revenue_account] => acc_28PGgHMdRskY4hnf
            [distribution_account] => acc_8XENmdYBRygQxubA
            [percent] => 10
            [is_active] => 1
            [shared] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [revenue_account] => acc_8XENmdYBRygQxubA
            [distribution_account] => acc_MVHYsAvJ5c9hjura
            [percent] => 10
            [is_active] => 1
            [shared] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [revenue_account] => acc_MVHYsAvJ5c9hjura
            [distribution_account] => acc_ndk1tzj57phsfcwv
            [percent] => 10
            [is_active] => 1
            [shared] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [revenue_account] => acc_MVHYsAvJ5c9hjura
            [distribution_account] => acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA
            [percent] => 6
            [is_active] => 1
            [shared] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [revenue_account] => acc_ndk1tzj57phsfcwv
            [distribution_account] => acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA
            [percent] => 10
            [is_active] => 1
            [shared] => 10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [revenue_account] => acc_sPvybHKQUw1J2nVA
            [distribution_account] => acc_28PGgHMdRskY4hnf
            [percent] => 10
            [is_active] => 1
            [shared] => 20
        )

)
```